Google Cloud Functions and Cloud SQL - Intermittent Connection Errors & SQL Admin Quota
I am connecting to Cloud SQL from my Python Cloud Function using the language connector as described in Google docs:
def connect_with_connector(connector: Connector) -> sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:
    def getconn() -> pg8000.dbapi.Connection:
        conn: pg8000.dbapi.Connection = connector.connect(
            "instance",
            "pg8000",
            user="service-account",
            db="db_name",
            enable_iam_auth=True,
        )
        return conn

    pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        "postgresql+pg8000://",
        creator=getconn,
        # ...
    )
    return pool

I pass in a connector from the function, then use SQLAlchemy for executing statements, and afterwards, I close pool and connection:
pool.dispose()
connector.close()

From the beginning, this seemed inefficient to me. It now works most of the time, but every few hours, I get a series of errors that I believe stem from too many connections being set up. It often starts with a Broken Pipe error, then followed by a series of 429 Rate Limit Reached errors from the Google Cloud SQL Admin API and it correlates with my (simple) cloud function reaching its memory limit.
The volume of calls my cloud functions get is not huge, we don't reach any other API rate limits by far.
Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this inside a serverless environment?

Can you have a look at this document and this thread. If this does not help, can you share error logs from google cloud console.

Can you elaborate when you're closing your connector? It's not clear if you're doing that after every invocation (which you don't want to do). The Connector should live for the lifetime of the function.

Its strange that after the pipe breaking later gives the "429 Rate Limit Reached", because usually that means you used more tokens than you were allowed in a given time frame.  Is there a function to display how many remaining tokens in a given time frame exist just so you can confirm your assumption?  Another thing is maybe now the datasets are larger than they were before so perhaps you can increase the timeout on the connection?  I'm not sure as to the proprietary limitations of google but in normal situations you can modify that.

@enocom Right now, it is on every invocation sadly. I tried putting it into the global scope of my Python cloud function but that didn't work, the initializations never happened then.

@easleyfixed I actually just found something out about this by looking at all my Google logs without any filters. Every few hours, something sends a lot of Connect requests to the SQL Admin API and this correlates with the errors. For example this morning, 137 requests within a few seconds. I have no idea why this happens or where exactly it is coming from, only that it is the service account used for my functions. It's no surprise the API at some point blocks it. It occurs regularly, but not in an exact interval.

Oh that makes sense.  Good job looking at the logs to find that out.  Do you think the requests are legit?  If so need to find out what is causing it, if not, need to find a way to block it.

Take a look at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector/issues/830#issuecomment-1699141112 -- that's a good example of how to properly initialize the Connector in a function.

This looks like a classic case of needing the lazy refresh option.
TL;DR:
connector = Connector(refresh_strategy="lazy")

Also, you'll want to lazily initialize your database connection (and avoid recreating the connector on every function call). Something like this:
import functions_framework
import sqlalchemy
import json
from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector, IPTypes
import pg8000


def connect_to_instance() -> sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:
    connector = Connector()

    def getconn() -> pg8000.dbapi.Connection:
        return connector.connect(
            "...", # the PostgreSQL's instance connection name here
            "pg8000",
            user     = "xyz",
            password = 'supersecret',
            db       = "db_name",
            ip_type  = IPTypes.PUBLIC
        )
    
    return sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        "postgresql+pg8000://",
        creator      = getconn,
        pool_size    = 5,
        max_overflow = 2,
        pool_timeout = 30,
        pool_recycle = 1800
    )


# lazy initialization of global db
db = None


@functions_framework.http
def hello_http(request):
    an_id = request.args["ID"]
    # lazy init within request context
    global db
    if not db:
        db = connect_to_instance()
    with db.connect() as conn:
        select_stmt = sqlalchemy.text(
            "SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3,"
            " FROM table_1"
            " WHERE col_1 = :some_id"
            " AND col_2 > 0"
        )
        
        fetch_result = conn.execute(
            select_stmt,
            {"some_id": an_id}
        ).fetchall()

    ost_inv = [list(o) for o in fetch_result]
    
    return json.dumps({"fetch_result": fetch_result}, default = str), 200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"}


Thank you so much! This seems to be working very well. However, I now get this error regularly:
Unclosed client session client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x3e7b3e03fb60>
The memory address varies of course. Do you have an idea how I could mitigate that?  I am disposing pools and closing connectors explicitly after usage.
